# How to check the last edited time in Google Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

Is there a way to check last edit time in google colab? 
Specificly in read only mode?
Tried in the google colab ui and didn't find any solution..

Answer (score 3):

In "File > Revision History" maybe?

Answer (score 0):

For Drive notebooks, select 'Locate in Drive' from the File menu. Then, right click, select 'Show details', and you'll see the last modified time among the info listed.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your ipynb file and choose "Manage Versions" then you can see last versions.
You can also keep some versions forever.