# How do I re-obtain code of a still running fuction in Colaboratory?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

a total beginner here. By being dumb, I accidentally deleted a function I have been working on for almost 2 hours and then overwrote the undo possibility. The previous version of the function is still active (I can call it) and I was wondering whether there is a way to recover the code or if I have to start all over again. I couldn't find an answer online so I came here.
Thank you in advance for any answers.

Comment: It looks like this question has been asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54117137/how-to-check-the-last-edited-time-in-google-colab

Answer (score 0):

Did some more searching and found a similar question which presented a solution.

```
import inspect
inspect.getsource(function)
```

Using this I managed to get the source code back as a string with \n formating. Although setting such a code is going to take a while, it is definitely faster than rewriting it.
However, I wonder if perhaps there is a different or better solution.

Comment: Can't you just `print` the string?